# Change admin privileges after copying an exe file programmatically

Tags: c#, admin, privileges

I've been programming in C# for quite sometime now. I've got lot of help from you'll during the past few days. But I'm stuck here...

I have built an .exe file and changed the manifest so that on execution it needs administrative privileges. I changed the following in the manifest

```
requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"
```

This would prompt a UAC window which would inform the user that the .exe file requires admin privileges.

Now, I've made my .exe file to copy itself in another location on the local machine. But the catch is, the copied file also requires admin privileges when I run it. I want to edit the privileges of that copied file. I want the copied file to have no such constraint of admin privileges. I want to make it run normally.

I need this done because I've made the .exe file to change the registry which calls the copied .exe file at every startup. I've noticed that with the copied .exe file having admin privileges, the registry tweak doesn't work. Although it works perfectly when the .exe file doesn't require any admin privileges.

Is there a way out of this?

Comment: Don't think its possible.. only solution I can think of is by building two versions of your executable, one with an administrator execution level and another one with an invoker level.